# Python aiogram: state switch

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

I am learning aiogram, and trying to get some messages as args for funtion call. As I learned from internet I should use State Machine

First I ask for some args and change state, to catch next message

```py
@dp.message_handler(text='Parse', state="*")
async def process_parse_command(msg: types.Message):
    await msg.reply(f"What words to watch for?\n", reply_markup=remove_kb)
    stat = dp.current_state(user=msg.from_user.id)
    await stat.set_state(SomeStates.PARSING_WORD)
```

Next I try to catch any message when I am on another state

```py
@dp.message_handler(state=SomeStates.PARSING_WORD)
async def process_parse_word(msg: types.Message):
    argument = message.get_args()
    print(argument)
    stat = dp.current_state(user=msg.from_user.id)
    print(stat)
```

upd: this is my utils file

```py
from aiogram.utils.helper import Helper, HelperMode, ListItem
class SomeStates(Helper):
    mode = HelperMode.snake_case

    MAIN_MENU = ListItem()
    PARSING_WORD = ListItem()
    PARSING_NUMBER = ListItem()
    HELP_MENU = ListItem()
    FAQ_MENU = ListItem()
```

But second message_handler is never called
[TG screenshot][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/81edC.png

Maybe I got something wrong about State Machine, but in the example lesson everything worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are StatesGroup Class in aiogram, rewrite your code like this and it works

```
class SomeStates(StatesGroup):
    MAIN_MENU = State()
    PARSING_WORD = State()
    PARSING_NUMBER = State()
    HELP_MENU = State()
    FAQ_MENU = State()
    

@dp.message_handler(text='Parse', state="*")
async def process_parse_command(msg: types.Message):
    await msg.reply(f"What words to watch for?\n")
    stat = dp.current_state(user=msg.from_user.id)
    print(stat)
    await stat.set_state(SomeStates.PARSING_WORD)


@dp.message_handler(state=SomeStates.PARSING_WORD)
async def process_parse_word(msg: types.Message):
    # there was a mistake here
    # argument = message.get_args() - NameError: name 'message' is not defined
    # argument = msg.get_args() # None is here, better use message.text
    argument = msg.text
    print(argument) 
    stat = dp.current_state(user=msg.from_user.id)
    print(stat)
```

---

[Aiogram official documentation](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html) using StatesGroup for FSM

Comment: Thnx, I solved it myself a few days ago and forgot to update my question :)
I used in custom class *ListItems* instead of *State* because guide I was using was not very good